# What are the tax implications of a US account for a non-resident?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, form-w-8-ben

I've successfully opened a US checking bank account with Chase with my H1B-visa passport, listing the address of a friend of mine who is a national as my residence address. I've been wondering if treating this account as a savings account where my salary is sent to via Direct Deposit but wiring part of that to my account in Colombia is a good idea from a tax/law standpoint, especially considering that I actually work for an US company as a foreign contractor.

I've signed a W8-BEN declaring that I don't have to pay any US taxes, but I'm wondering if actually holding money in the US may void that document? Would the IRS have grounds to go after me? I'd be receiving 4000 USD monthly and wiring 3500 USD to Colombia monthly.

I do not intend to use the account as a sort of tax-evasion scheme, as I plan to report my overseas assets to the DIAN, Colombia's equivalent of the IRS. Moreover, Chase asked me to provide my national tax id and I replied truthfully.

Bonus points: Could not actually living at the residence address provided ever be grounds for account termination? My friend is able to forward any documents that Chase sends me to my actual residence, and I set things up so Chase sends all documents to me electronically. Chase provided me with a Visa debit card which I plan to use in Colombia.